# if i use Unique Device ID for iOS apple store will reject my app ? best option

Tags: ios

I heard that if I use the Unique Identification of iOS device in my app Apple will reject it is that true? , I am going to make an app, but I have a question what the best option to use Apple devices unique id in my app so I can know if the user has deleted the app or upgrade it as well I will make this unique id as a unique id in my table in the database so I know the user account without login and I allow the user to make a post without showing the unique id in the UI and give them random username for every post like use16672, or user2162 . I hope is that makes sense my English is the second language sorry thank you

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, case by case.
I had 2 apps using Unique Device ID.
One is rejected, another one is passed.
I don't recommend that.

Comment: did you find best solution for that?

Comment: unfortunately, no.
I just made own unique id in my code using random number and character :(

Answer (score 0):

Apple does not want you to access the specific device id. If you want a unique number for each device for your app, generate a UUID the first time the app runs and store it in user preferences.

The downside to this is that if the user uninstalls the app and installs it later, that UUID will be replaced by a new one.

Comment: I like this solution as well  and it  will be the last solution to start  with if i don't find other way, thank you

Comment: what about if I save the UUID in txt file in the device storage so i can check if the user reinstall?